# custom name resolution failing on docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dns

I want to customize the DNS configuration for a new container. I am using the --hostname flag to set the
hostname of a new container. Below is the docker command for testing the hostname:

```
docker run --rm --hostname rando alpine:latest nslookup rando
```

The output is like below:

```
Server:     xxx.xxx.xxx.2
Address:    xxx.xxx.xxx.2:53

** server can't find rando.localdomain: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find rando.localdomain: NXDOMAIN
```

I am using the ubuntu 19.10 version. Below is the content from the `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver xxx.xxx.xx.2
search localdomain
```

I will appreciate any help in solving this issue.

Regards,
Rando.

P.S

I tried to create the bridge network explicitly but still didn't work. Below is the result of the execution:

[image]

Below is the content from `/etc/resolv.conf` file inside container:
[image]

Below is the docker version:
[image]

Latest trials:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two small inaccuracies in your attempt:

The `--hostname` option does not create a DNS entry. It simply sets the hostname in the container.

More over, containers that use the default bridge network, get a copy of `/etc/resolv.conf` file from the host(this NS knows nothing about the container names), whereas containers that use a custom network use Docker’s embedded DNS server, which forwards external DNS lookups to the DNS servers configured on the host.

You can use `--name` and/or `--net-alias` to have the DNS entry created.

Three commands are better than 1000 words:

```
// Creating a custom docker bridge network
docker network create -d bridge so-demo

// Running the container in the network created above
docker run -it --network so-demo --name foo --net-alias bar --hostname foobar alpine:latest sh


// Check if the container name is resolved:
/ # nslookup foo
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11:53
Non-authoritative answer:
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   foo
Address: 172.22.0.2


// Check if the net-alias is resolved
/ # nslookup bar
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11:53
Non-authoritative answer:
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   bar
Address: 172.22.0.2


// The hostname is not resolved
/ # nslookup foobar
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11:53
** server can't find foobar: NXDOMAIN
** server can't find foobar: NXDOMAIN


// ...the hostname is just set internally in the container: 
/ # hostname -f
foobar
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.11
```

Comment: Thank you for taking you time to answer this question. I tried your solution, but still got the same result. I have added a photo that shows the result from execution of   the commands suggested by you.

Comment: Quite hard to replicate on my end hence it just works, but let's try to compare: Can you check the content of the `/etc/resolv.conf` inside the container that you launched in the custom bridge network? Mine looks like this `nameserver 127.0.0.11 \n options ndots:0`.  Can you get rid of the search domain `localdomain`? Have you customized anything on top of the default docker settings? What docker version are you using? In <v1.10 things were implemented differently. Do you have swarm enabled?

Comment: I edited the question to include the docker version and also the content from the ```/etc/resolv.conf``` file.

Comment: The only strange thing I can spot is that the `.localdomain` suffix is added to the lookup queries you are performing. This is not the default behavior and I have no idea how to reproduce and find an answer. Try to add a trailing dot in in the lookup: `nslookup net-demo.` and see if this changes something

Comment: `docker inspect 7b79d6857006 | grep -i dns` on my end returns default configs: `"Dns": [], "DnsOptions": [], "DnsSearch": []`.

Comment: I added the result from running the command you suggested in the question. docker inspect return the same result, but the ```nslookup ``` it returned a non-authorietative

Comment: So when you added the dot in `nslookup net-demo.` it was correctly resolved to the IP address of the container?

Comment: It is very strange, why it is the returning a non-authoritative answer when I am fetching from the authoritative server. Second, why isn't able to resolve the hostname demo, since it is present in /etc/hosts. I am understanding this behaviour of this container...